# How to use the wpf treeview with nested objects of different types

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have two classes that I'd like to show in a treeview.

In my main window, I have an observable collection of a certain type of object, call it object a.
Object a contains an observable collection of another type of object, object b.
Each object b contains an observable collection of object b's.

For example, I might have something that looks like this

ListOfObjectA's

-ObjectA1

--ListOfObjectB's

---ObjectB

----ListOfObjectB's

-----ObjectB

-ObjectA2

--ListOfObjectB's

---ObjectB

What should my xaml look like to bind the treeview to something like that?

Sorry if I'm not explaining this well, I'm new to wpf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RB has the right idea. This is where WPF's ability to apply templates to normal .NET objects becomes very powerful.

You need to specify two `HierarchicalDataTemplates`, one for objects of type `a`, and the other for objects of type `b`. Something like this :

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:a}">
            <!-- XAML to display objects of type a -->
        </HierarchialDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:b}">
            <!-- XAML to display objects of type b -->
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

You will need to specify bindings for the `ItemsSource` property of each template so that WPF knows where to get child objects from. Also, you'll need to add an `xmlns` declaration to the root node specifying the namespace that the objects live in (represented by `local` in the sample code above).

Answer (score 1):

I know enough WPF to be really dangerous, but I'm pretty sure the HierarchicalDataTemplate is the solution to your problem.  My XAML skill are iffy, so I am can't write good example code for you.  Here is how I used the HierarchicalDataTemplate in my project.  I hope this gives you some good ideas.

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" 
          Grid.Column="1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" 
          SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged" 
          ContextMenu="{StaticResource MenuContextMenu}">

  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
      <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemName}" Margin="5,0,5,0" />-->
      <Grid  ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenu}"   >
        <TextBlock  Name="ShownItem" 
                          Text="{Binding Path=ItemName}" 
                          Margin="0,0,0,0" />

          <TextBox Name="EditBox" 
                 Text="{Binding Path=ItemName}" 
                 Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility}"
                 Style="{StaticResource EditableTextBox}" 
                 IsVisibleChanged="EditBox_IsVisibleChanged"
                 PreviewKeyDown="EditBox_KeyDown"
                 Margin="0,2,0,2"
                   >

              </TextBox>

      </Grid>
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```