# Show multiple types in tree view with labels wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to show multiple types in the tree view

I have Projects, which contain workspaces

[image: Here is the image]

When Projects are expanded can see list of workspaces.

I have tried using `<TreeViewItem Header="My Projects" ItemSource="{Binding Projects}">` but "My Projects" is becoming a root node and Project1, Project2... becomes its child nodes.

Also I have tried a Label with "My Projects" inside the treeview but could get to show as needed.

So Finally I ended up with a tree view for Projects and Followed by another tree view for Workspaces.

Is it possible to implement this in a single tree view?

Comment: I think fallow like solution is so good

[WPF Treeview Databinding Hierarchal Data with mixed types][question].

[question]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673173/wpf-treeview-databinding-hierarchal-data-with-mixed-types/3673232#3673232

Answer (score 0):

Try adding different `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s for `Project` type and `Workspace` type separately instead of directly creating `TreeViewItem`s inside:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="model:Project (Whatever type you are using for Project)" ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="model:Workspace (Whatever type you are using for Workspace)">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: See the problem here is adding section/group names "My Projects" and "My Workspaces". Not showing the Hierarchical data.