# TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplates for more than one collection type

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a Projects collection that contains two collections (either of which can be empty):

```
class Project {  
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

I can get the nested Projects to display:

```
<TreeView  x:Name="ProjectsTree" >
<TreeViewItem Header="Projects" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectsCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              IsExpanded="True" >
    <TreeViewItem.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Project}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeViewItem.Resources>
</TreeViewItem>
```

How do I add a 2nd template for Tasks?  If I add:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Project}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I get an error about there already being an entry in the resource dictionary for datatype 'Project' (or something like that).

All help would be appreciated...

Comment: This looked promising -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673173/wpf-treeview-databinding-hierarchal-data-with-mixed-types -- but I couldn't figure out how to get it working in my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: the `Project` is given and cannot be changed. That means in the context of MVVM `Project` is the model. You can now create a view model that connects the view and model. It could look like this:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return Project.Name;
        }
    }

    public int Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return Project.Priority;
        }
    }

    public IList Children
    {
        get
        {
            if (Project.Projects.Count > 0)
            {
                return Project.Projects;
            }

            return Project.Tasks;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you adapt the template to the view model and you are done:

```
    <TreeView  x:Name="ProjectsTree" >
        <TreeViewItem Header="Projects" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectsViewModelCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          IsExpanded="True" >
            <TreeViewItem.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Project}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem.Resources>
        </TreeViewItem>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your answer, combined with some answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912481/wpf-treeview-hierarchicaldatatemplate-binding-to-object-with-multiple-child-co, helped me get it working.