# WPF: Add multiple level with different types items to TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a class `(ClassA)` that contains two different types of lists, `List of ClassBTypes` and `List of ClassC`. `ClassBTypes` has its own `List of ClassB`.

I want to achieve the below structure for the TreeView

```
-- ClassAName   
-- -- ClassBType1Name  
-- -- -- ClassB1Name  
-- -- -- ClassB2Name     
-- -- ClassBType2Name  
-- -- -- ClassB1Name  
-- -- -- ClassB2Name  
-- -- ClassC1Name  
-- -- ClassC2Name
```

I managed to get the tree to draw the `ClassA` and `ClassB`, but couldn't figure out how to add `ClassC` to the `Tree resources`.
Please check the below source code.

Test.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Test : Window {    
    InitializeComponent();
    var a = new List<ClassA>{new ClassA(), new ClassA()};
    treeView.ItemsSource = a;
}
```

C# classes:

```
public class ClassA{    
    // initiate obj    
    public string Name {get; set;}     
    public List<ClassBTypes> Btypes {get; set;}     
    public List<ClassC> C {get; set;}    
}    
public class ClassBTypes{    
    public string Name {get; set;}    
    public List<ClassB> B {get; set;}   
}    
public class ClassB{    
    public string Name {get; set;}    
}     
public class ClassC{   
    public string Name {get; set;}   
}
```

xaml code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="aKey">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="bKey"
               ItemsSource="{Binding B}"
               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource aKey}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="bTypeKey"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Btypes}"
               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource bKey}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>   
.....     
<Grid>
   <TreeView Name="treeView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource bTypeKey}" />
</Grid>
```

How to add the `ClassC list` from `ClassA` obj, I've added the below code to `<Window.Resources>` but how can I added it to treeView resources.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="bTypeKey"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Btypes}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource bKey}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate - binding to object with multiple child collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912481/wpf-treeview-hierarchicaldatatemplate-binding-to-object-with-multiple-child-co)

Comment: @ASh it's not since I need to build the tree with two different types of children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by combine the two types of lists to [CompositeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx).
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3673232/1383836) for more details.